# Facebook & Google Omniauth & Rails app with auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authorization, omniauth

I am trying to let my users to login via Facebook, Google or with a user form. I have searched couple of topics on web and stackoverflow. But I still have a small problem could not figure it out.

I have a user form where user has to fill;

```
name
username
email
password
password_confirmation
```

Then I created another model called `identity`. 
It looks like this;

```
class Identity < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates_presence_of :user_id, :uid, :provider
    validates_uniqueness_of :uid, :scope => :provider


 def self.find_from_hash(auth)
    find_by_provider_and_uid(auth.provider, auth.uid)
 end

 def self.create_from_hash(auth, user = nil)
    user ||= User.create_from_hash!(auth)
    Identity.create(:user => user, :uid => auth.uid, :provider => auth.provider, :oauth_token => auth.credentials.token, :oauth_expires_at => Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at))
 end


end
```

In the sessions controller I have create action, that the user form comes here;

```
def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)


    respond_to do |format|
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      if user.admin?
        log_in user
        format.html { redirect_to admin_dashboard_path }
      elsif user.activated? 
        log_in user
        unread_conversation
        params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
        format.html { redirect_back_or user }
        flash[:notice] = t('flash.sessions.create.success.html')
        format.js 
      else
        format.html { redirect_to root_url }
        format.json { render json: {email:[t('header.n_activated')]} , status: :unprocessable_entity}
        format.js   { render json: {email:[t('header.n_activated')]}, status: :unprocessable_entity }

      end

    else
    format.html { redirect_to root_url }
    format.json { render json: {email: [t('header.invalid_combination')]} , status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.js   { render json: {email: [t('header.invalid_combination')]}, status: :unprocessable_entity }

    end
  end


  end
```

I also have `fbcreate` action, where I handle Facebook & Google login.

```
def fbcreate

  identity = env["omniauth.auth"]
  unless @identity = Identity.find_from_hash(identity)
    # Create a new user or add an auth to existing user, depending on
    # whether there is already a user signed in.
    #user = User.find_by_email(identity.info.email)
    @identity = Identity.create_from_hash(identity, current_user)
  end
    log_in @identity.user
    redirect_to root_url
end
```

In the sessions helper I have `current_user` action;

```
def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end
```

In user.rb

```
#Social media login
    def self.create_from_hash!(auth)
      create(:name => auth.info.name, :username => auth.info.name.partition(" ").first, :email => auth.info.email, :user_type => 'Personal Account', :password => auth.uid, :activated => true )
```

Ok. So my question is;

1. I have an email address demo1@gmail.com on facebook and demo2@gmail.com on google. How can understand these emails are the same person?
2. When I signup with the form I give my facebook email demo1@gmail.com then I want to attach facebook and google to this user as well.

The problem with this code `current_user` in `fbcreate` action is nil. If I find user with email, it works ok if user uses the same email for google and facebook. If one or more of them is different than the record (user signup with form) then new user is created. I do not want that. How can I overcome this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Analysing from outside in my opinion you need first to identify what account you are for your application.

1) If the demo2@gmail.com was not found you need to force your a user to login with email and password or with ominauth facebook (`user_signed_in? == true`) and create another a feature/view to attach omniauth accounts (google,git...)
[image]